# Multiply commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm new at Batch files, and my english might not be the best, but i'm going to give it a chance. 
**I'm on Windows.**

This is what my .bat file looks like at the moment.
The first command works.

```
@ECHO OFF 
start C:\steamcmd\steamcmd.exe +login anonymous +force_install_dir c:\CSS\ +app_update 232330 +quit
start C:\CSS\srcds.exe -console -game cstrike -maxplayers 12 +fps_max 200  -port 27016 +map de_dust2 -tickrate 100
```

But what I want to do is, after the **+quit**, I want to start the command:

```
start C:\CSS\srcds.exe -console -game cstrike -maxplayers 12 +fps_max  200
```

Delaying it won't work, since the first command updates the program I want to start in the second command.

Am I supposed to make a second batch file and call it right before the +quit, or is it possible to make this in a single batch file?

**EDIT** 
it occurred to me that calling another .bat file before the +quit, just starts both commands at the same time.

Thanks Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/w` will make the batch file wait until the first command has completed before launching the second one.

The `""` is there in both command to avoid a different issue with quoted terms in the commands - as a safeguard.

```
@ECHO OFF 
start "" /w C:\steamcmd\steamcmd.exe +login anonymous +force_install_dir c:\CSS\ +app_update 232330 +quit
start "" C:\CSS\srcds.exe -console -game cstrike -maxplayers 12 +fps_max 200  -port 27016 +map de_dust2 -tickrate 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Without actually executing the commands myself, I'd suggest

```
start /WAIT C:\steamcmd\steamcmd.exe +lo.....
```

The `/WAIT` means 'wait until the process terminates before continuing'

OR

```
call C:\steamcmd\steamcmd.exe +lo.....
```

which similarly should only proceed to the next step in the batch once `steamcmd.exe` terminates.